# Illegal offset type error in PHP

Tags: php

Alright, I'm a little lost. Here's my code, but how do I get rid of the PHP error that tells me it's an illegal offset type? I'm trying to cycle through the colors.

```
$color = array(

    [0]=>"red", 
    [1]=>"cherry",
    [2]=>"orange",
    [3]=>"amber",
    [4]=>"blue",
    [5]=>"sapphire",
    [6]=>"green",
    [7]=>"forest green",
    [8]=>"purple",
    [9]=>"lavender");
 //starts at index 0

for($colorCount=0; $colorCount <=9; $colorCount++){

    if ($colorCount == 9){
        break;
    }
    echo implode(", ", $color).", ";

}
```

Comment: That array definition is not valid syntax. Is this your actual code?

Comment: Remove the brackets from around your indices.

Comment: remove square brackets and put quotes or simple number

Comment: what are you trying to do .. print individual color or add some details to these color ..
As halcyon mention above array definition syntax  is not valid..

Comment: what version of php you use? in v5.5+ square brackets equivalents keyword `array`, i.e. you have the next code: `$color = array( array(0)=>"red", array(1)=>"cherry".. and so on` .. it's syntax error, I suggest you can't have an array as a key inside associative array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what might be happening is that, since PHP now supports short-array notation with `[]`. It's parsing `[0]` as `array(0)` which you then try to use as a key in an array, which is not allowed. This would explain that exact error message.

Declare your array like:

```
$color = array(
    0 => "red", 
    1 => "cherry",
    2 => "orange",
    3 => "amber",
    4 => "blue",
    5 => "sapphire",
    6 => "green",
    7 => "forest green",
    8 => "purple",
    9 => "lavender"
);
```

You can even leave off the numbers and do:

```
$color = array(
    "red", 
    "cherry",
    "orange",
    "amber",
    "blue",
    "sapphire",
    "green",
    "forest green",
    "purple",
    "lavender"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$color = array(

        '0'=>"red", 
        '1'=>"cherry",
        '2'=>"orange",
        '3'=>"amber",
        '4'=>"blue",
        '5'=>"sapphire",
        '6'=>"green",
        '7'=>"forest green",
        '8'=>"purple",
        '9'=>"lavender"
        );
foreach ($color as $key => $res) {
       print_r($res);
}
```

Comment: Adding the quotes doesn't do anything, PHP will interpret keys that look like integers as integers. The original code also seems to imply integers are to be used.

Comment: as first i was just trying to say that the array definition is not valid.

and the reason i  posted  my answer was .. if he wants anything else if array is valid .. Thank you